# Xcode project doesn't open

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I tried to open file .xcodepoj, but only one file is opened by Xcode, it is - main.m.

[image]

Help me please! How should I open project? What is the problem?

Comment: look at screenshot. but i dont think, that it will help you

Comment: I'm not trying to be demeaning or anything because this happened to me and It took almost about 10 minutes to fix, click view, then click show toolbar. Hopefully that's the problem for you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had similar problem a few days ago. Way to "fix" it:

- Expand the toolbar
- Open the side windows that you need(probably the left one only)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 11):

This is how I restored it to the normal view.

- View > Show Toolbar
- View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator

Optionally

- View > Debug Area > Activate Console
- View > Utilities > Show Utilities

Xcode should now be in the state you want it.

Comment: Yup this is what worked for me. Check the "view" menu at the top it should give you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Why did this happen?**

Double click on one of your app file, it is gonna open in a new naked editor. Close the the Xcode app, before closing the recent opened window. Close Xcode. Open your app again, and here we are.

**Solution:**

you can `Alt + click on the arrows` to expand all the hierarchy.